# Have MessageBox appear once (code inside timer)

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

UPDATE: I've managed to fix my problem. Using the code below, I moved my MessageBox AFTER my XML saving and changed the Timer from 100ms to 400ms. I now have 1 box appear, thank god. Although If anyone has a short cut to updating a single value (ActReminded) in the List array(ActListTask), that'd be great to know.

I'm having a little issue with displaying the MessageBox. Show inside a timer without it spamming me. Here's the part of the code I've been working with:

```
public class ActiveTasks
    {
        //Properties here
    }

public List<ActiveTasks> ActTaskList = new List<ActiveTasks>();

for (int i = 0; i < ListActive.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (DTime.Date == newDateTime.Date)
            {
                if (newDateTimeLeft.CompareTo(TimeSpan.Zero) <= 0 && ActTaskList[i].ActReminded != "true")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("!!!!");
                    ActTaskList.Add(new ActiveTasks()
                    {
                        ActTitle = ActTaskList[i].ActTitle,
                        ActDesc = ActTaskList[i].ActDesc,
                        ActDate = ActTaskList[i].ActDate,
                        ActTime = ActTaskList[i].ActTime,
                        ActStatus = ActTaskList[i].ActStatus,
                        ActReminded = "true",
                        ActRepeat = ActTaskList[i].ActRepeat
                    });

                    ListActive.Items.RemoveAt(i);

                    ActTaskList.RemoveAt(i);

                    XDocument XmlActTasks = GenerateActiveListToXML(ActTaskList);
                }
            }
        }
```

I actually decided I may want to hold onto the reminder status, whether it has been shown or not as I wouldn't want a repeated reminder every time the program is opened. Since I don't know of a way to update an individual part of ActTaskList I just re-added it, and then deleted the original. This code manages to recognise that if it happens, it will change the reminder status from false, to true; after I've Ok'ed all the spam. So it will stop the MessageBox once I've managed to closed all the Messageboxes. However, it doesn't stop the spam. Would it be anything to do with the fact I've set the timer to 100ms? Or could their be an alternative way to make the messagebox appear without it being inside the timer?

Comment: Where's you code declaring the timer? Which type of timer are you using?

Comment: Have a `bool`, when the user gets presented, set the `bool` to false, only alert when the `bool` is true.

Comment: **What are you trying to accomplish?** From the sounds of it, you want one messagebox after a certain delay. Is that what you want?

Comment: have you tried "if (Date.Equals(newDateTime))" ?

Comment: @p4bl0: That won't help. It still compares `Ticks`. (This is not Java `;)`)

Comment: @minitech I know, but since his initial thought was Date == newDateTime and in my experience it (almost) never returns true so I suggested that. honestly it's not very clear what he needs

Comment: @p4bl0: `.Equals` does *exactly the same thing except less concisely* is all I'm saying :)

Comment: Sorry guys, I'm not 100% pro with C# so there may be some things I may not understand. Basically, I'm set up on WinFom in VS and I've set a timer. I've tried a bool command, but it didn't stop the spam.

Basically, what I'm trying to do is a reminder function. So when an arrays time equals today w/ time display message.

Answer (score 1):

The odds of the current time lining up exactly to the second what is happening in your loop is    small.  Why not treat newDateTime as a cut off point and just set a flag?

```
//Declare this outside of the loop
bool hasDisplayed = false;

//Inside the timer event handler
if (!hasDisplayed && DateTime.Now >= newDateTime)
{
    hasDisplayed = true;

    MessageBox.Show("!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you do something like this?

```
Action message = () => MessageBox.Show("!!!!!!!!!!!!!"));
object lockOb = new object();

void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    lock(lockOb)
        if(null != message)
        {
            message();
            message = null;
        }
}
```

Comment: This just makes the messagebox spam me to death.

Comment: I edited and added a lock.  That is really your issue, because of the 'Ok' button waiting for you to return, it never gets set to null.  But with the lock, it won't check to do the message again until after the lock exits.

Comment: Your update doesn't fix it. Give me a sec, I'll update my original question.

Comment: Do you want the message box to show up after a delayed time or when the time meets a certain value?

Comment: I want it to show when the values are equal to one another, check my question, I've updated it. Hopefully it'll help you understand what I'm doing.

Comment: Do what RQDQ suggested with a bool flag, that seems like it'd stop the spam.

Answer (score 0):

You say you've already tried a boolean indicating the message has already been shown, I'm assuming because the code probably looked like it did below.

```
void TimerLoop()
{
    bool msgAlreadyShown;

    if(!msgAlreadyShown)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("!!!!!!!");
    }
    // Other work in your timer function
}
```

The problem with that code is that the bool will be set to false each time the function is called by the timer.  You haven't posted much code, but you've at least stated what you're trying to accomplish, a timer that checks if a reminder should be presented to the user.

I'm about to make some wild guesses about how you've put together your software, there's a good chance it's way off, but I hope it might point you in the right direction.  You could have some sort of reminder class like this:

```
public class Reminder
{
    string Message { get; set;}
    DateTime Alarm { get; set; } 
    bool IsDismissed { get; set; }
}
```

I'm assuming you might want to have multiple reminders that can be checked for in the timer loop, so your timer loop could look something like:

```
private List<Reminder> _activeReminders; // A list of reminders

void TimerLoop(object s, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    lock(_activeReminders) 
    {
        var now = DateTime.Now;
        foreach(var reminder in _activeReminders)
        {
            // only run this code if the time has passed and it hasn't already
            // been shown
            if(now.CompareTo(reminder.Alarm) >= 0 && !reminder.IsDismissed)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(reminder.Message);
                reminder.IsDismissed = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is a pretty naive implementation, since you probably don't want to hold onto the reminders for forever and the reminders are never removed from the `_activeReminders` list, but you essentially just need to add some sort of state to determine if the reminder has already been shown.

Of course, this isn't a complete example either, since I never new up the `_activeReminders` field or add anything to it, but I think this might help get the idea of what you need to do across.  Also, you might not care about multiple reminders, and your timer code could look nothing like this.  The main idea was to show you how you can keep track of the state of a reminder, and tailor it to your own code.  The above was just an example.

Also, I haven't actually tested it, so treat it more like pseudocode than anything else.  However, the logic is sound, and should it should only cause the message box to appear once.

Comment: This was slightly helpful. Since I already have some Lists, I just added another public string in the class (since I'm too lazy to figure out how to read bool from XML right now). However, it doesn't stop the spamming of the Messagebox.

Comment: @MattVon - Then your issue might lie somewhere else, or you didn't translate the code above exactly as it is, to work with your application.  I just tested the above code, and it doesn't spam me.  If you removed the lock on `_activeReminders`, it's possible that the timer could be executed again while the code is executing `MessageBox.Show()`, since it (might) block the thread.  In that case, you'll need to set `IsDismissed` to true *before* you show the messagebox.  Past that, I'm not sure I can help much without actually looking at your code.